# Destination account of the Slashing function in Currency trait

Tags: slashing

Is there a way to configure the destination account when using  the Slashing function from `Trait frame_support::traits::tokens::currency::Currency`?

Kazu

**Edit**

As I'm using the `reserve` function from the `ReservableCurrency` trait, instead of using the slash function of the currency trait, I will use the `repatriate_reserved` function of the `ReservableCurrency` trait.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trait name [`OnUnbalanced`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.OnUnbalanced.html).

It's a hook. And you could write some logic like if somebody got slash then trigger it.

Here's an example. Treasury pallet defines an `OnSlash` configuration. You could configure where the [slashed balance](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L377) go.

The example's configuration is [`()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1056). Here's the [implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/imbalance/on_unbalanced.rs#L55). It does nothing, which means the token just burned. You could implement your owned logic then pass it to `OnSlash`.

---

BTW, If you want to slash some token from the 'bad guy' and reward someone. Why not use `transfer` or `withdraw`/`issue`/`burn`?